# How to disable "ipad-compatibility" on Trigger.io?

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I need my app be runnable only on iphone and not on iPAD! How to set this?

Comment: When you submit your app to the app store.. Apple doesn't allow you to set the "iPhone only" option?

Comment: We have a ticket open to let you build / package for only iPhone or iPad and I'll report back here. Email support@trigger.io and we'll add your email address to the ticket also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We included support for this in v1.4.16 of the platform: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-16.

For documentation, see http://current-docs.trigger.io/modules/requirements.html#modules-requirements.