# Using Trigger.IO to Create iPhone ONLY App

Tags: trigger.io

I'm trying to compile the app so that it is iPhone sized only but I don't see a way to do this with Trigger.io. It's OK if it runs on the iPad but I don't want it to be a native iPad app.

Suggestions on how do I get it to do that?

Comment: This question might be related to the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349593/how-to-disable-ipad-compatibility-on-trigger-io).. Although I think he wants to totally restrict it from running on the iPad. I only want it to be sized ONLY for iPhone but still run on the iPad.

Comment: If I understand what you mean you should be able to do this through your CSS - just use max-width and max-height.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the requirements module: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/requirements.html#ios. E.g. in your `config.json`:

```
"requirements": {
    "ios": {
        "device_family": "iphone"
    }
}
```